# Как правильно сделать фильтр с несколькими полями для таблицы html?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

Здравствуйте, делаю фильтр таблицы вот здесь [ktg.megusto.kz](http://ktg.megusto.kz) , и нужно как-то правильно оформить фильтр, уже все перепробовал, и ничего не нашел, сейчас код такой

```
require_once "core/db_config.php";
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
$fields = array('order_user', 'method', 'data_from', 'data_to');
$conditions = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_GET[$field]) && $_GET[$field] != '') {
        $conditions[] = "`$field` LIKE '%" . $_GET[$field] . "%'";
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `ktg_base`";
if (count($conditions) > 0) {
    $sql .= "WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}
} else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `ktg_base` WHERE del = 0";
}
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($sql));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<tr data-id="' . $row['id'] . '">';
echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['order_user'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['organizator'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['method'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['data_from'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['data_to'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

Как бы должно все работать но работает как-то не ясно, как тут правильно сделать ? там все 3 селетка, и одно поле для поиска по всей таблице.

Comment: Как минимум первый же забредший кулхацкер сломает ваш сайт и удалит все из БД. потому что в полях произвольный SQL запрос напишет. Используйте привязываемые переменные http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  А так по вопросу не понятно, что такое "работает как то не ясно"

Comment: ну по этой ссылке можете посмотреть http://ktg.megusto.kz/, как работает фильтр, как то не понятно